# Как запретить перетаскивать ползунок в type="range"

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

Помогите пожалуйста, необходимо запретить изменять значения слайдера пользователю, disabled="true" не подходит тк слайдер становиться бледным."

```
    $(element).html("<div class=\"main\">\n" +
        "  <input\n" +
        "      type=\"range\"\n" +
        "      class=\"slider\"\n" +
        "      name=\"participants\"\n" +
        "      id=\"rangeId\"\n" +
        "      min=\"1\"\n" +
        "      max=\"100\"\n" +
        "  >\n" +
        "  <span draggable='false' class=\"rangeslider__tooltip\" id =\"range-tooltip\"></span>\n" +
        "</div>");
```

Comment: Попробуйте  `readonly`.

Comment: readonly у меня не работает

Comment: Покажите пример, где не работает?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь пожалуйста https://codepen.io/alexey-sherstobitov/pen/BaWjdGQ

Comment: `readonly` на range в некоторых браузерах не работает, `disabled` лучше все же под это. Уберите `.rangeslider--disabled` opacity и будет не прозрачный

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Еще можно сделать вот так.

```css
.my-class {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" name="participants" min="5" max="51" value="20" class="my-class">
```

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы запретить посетителю перетаскивать ползунок, можно перекрыть его прозрачным элементом div с такими же размерами и абсолютными координатами:

```css
.myclass{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input type=range class=myclass />
<div class=myclass></div>
```

Или вариант, похожий на Ваш:

```css
#mydiv{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=element></div>
<div id=mydiv></div>
<script>
 $(element).html("<div class=\"main\">\n" +
        "  <input\n" +
        "      type=\"range\"\n" +
        "      class=\"slider\"\n" +
        "      name=\"participants\"\n" +
        "      id=\"rangeId\"\n" +
        "      min=\"1\"\n" +
        "      max=\"100\"\n" +
        "  >\n" +
        "  <span draggable='false' class=\"rangeslider__tooltip\" id =\"range-tooltip\"></span>\n" +
        "</div>");
</script>
```

Теперь по поводу Вашего codepen: перепишите объявление класса myclass так:

```css
.myclass{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 35%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

И ползунок заблокируется.

Comment: Влзглаяните пожалуйста https://codepen.io/alexey-sherstobitov/pen/BaWjdGQ, codepen не работает и у меня в коде тоже.

Comment: Так ка несовпадают позиции ползунка и заслоняющего дива.

Comment: Ещё в объявлении myclass вначале нужен не диез, а точка.

Comment: Добавил решение в конец ответа.